# Number applications to the French Government Defense's PhD grant (Direction Générale de l'Armement, in short DGA)

Tags: data-request, research, france

I am looking for the number applications to the French Government Defense ([Direction Générale de l'Armement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direction_g%C3%A9n%C3%A9rale_de_l%27armement), in short DGA)'s PhD grant (a.k.a. "[Bourse DGA](http://www.laas.fr/1-28747-Bourse-DGA.php)") each year. I know that the number of accepted candidates is around 130 ([source 1](http://www.iedu.fr/fiche.php?page=Financement&id=579), [source 2](https://www.ixarm.com/Theses-DGA)), but I wonder how many applications there are, and how this number of applications has changed throughout the years.